# How do I view comments in Microsoft Word 2011 for OSX?

Tags: macos, ms-office

How do I view comments in Microsoft Word 2011 for OSX?  I can turn on the review pane, but that shows me every edit I've done to this document and it's impossible to find the comments.  I just want a quick view of all the comments in the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your solution.  From the Review tab, under Tracking, select the *Show Markup* drop down and uncheck everything but comments.

[image: Show Markup Dropdown]

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  For long documents it appears that it takes a few seconds for the review pane to upate after making changes in the drop down menu.  I tried your suggestion and when it didn't seem to do anything I changed it back right away.  Waiting a few more seconds allowed the review pane to update and show me what i was looking for

Comment: It might not take as long if it was the default view for review.  Unfortunately, I can't test that since they didn't expose that feature under Preferences.